# How would I set the equation number for an EquationNumbered cell?

Tags: formatting, cells

Regardless of how many EquationNumbered cells are above or below, every new EquationNumbered cell that I add in my notebook shows (1) as  the equation number.

Is there a way to correct the equation numbering?

Comment: Is this a cell style you created yourself -- if so please show us the code -- or from a stylesheet?

Comment: This is the standard Mathematica 10 EquationNumbered cell.  After adding equations (1), (2), (3) and (5).  Added an EquationNumbered cell in the same section and instead of (5), I get (1).  So two EquationNumbered cells as equation (1) in the same section.

Comment: Slight edit - after adding equations (1),(2),(3) and (4), and another EquationNumbered cell gives me a new cell in the same section numbered (1).

Comment: Which stylesheet?

Comment: Hi Mike - this is a JournalArticle stylesheet.

Comment: An additional note. If you save the notebook and re-open the existing EquationNumbered cells show the equation numbers and cell brackets corresponding to EquationNumbered cell type but the cell style in the Formatting tool bar is blank.  If you change the style to EquationNumbered the equation number (of course) resets to 1.

Comment: One way to address this is to convert all Section, SubSection, Subsubsection cells to Text cells.  For each EquationNumbered Cell toggle between Equation and EquationNumbered.  EquationNumbered cells seem to key on section cells for numbering.  After converting all Section cells to Text, EquationNumbered cells started working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround than a solution.  This approach may be useful as a starting point to debug the notebook.

I don't see this as a solution as more knowledgeable folks such as Mr. Honeychurch may have much better input. While this worked - there are probably better approaches.

To locate points where equation numbering re-starts at (1)

1. Make a backup of your notebook and temporarily convert Section, Subsection, Subsubsection cells in the notebook to text cells.
2. From the top of the notebook, convert the EquationNumbered cells to Equation cells.  Then change the cell type from Equation to EquationNumbered.

The equation numbers should now be sequential.

The natural follow on is to convert the Text cells back to Section and Subsection, ... headings - watching for issues with equation numbers.